# Unchecked angularJS Checkbox When Select Option CHanges

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

```
<select ng-model="select">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
</select>
```

when select value is 1,3 I want to show the checkbox

```
<input type=checkbox name="ccp" ng-model="ccp" ng-show="select.val==1 || select.val==2">
```

the Problem is when I select 1 then checkbox is visible, and I checked the checkbox. but when I change the select option the checkbox is invisible but its with checked. I want when I select option changes I want uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: you should reset the value of `ccp` on change of selected option, set it to false if its invisible

Comment: Hard to check this without a fiddle, have you tried to access the value without ".val", because "select" should already hold the value.
    ng-show="select == 1 || select == 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

```
<select ng-model="select" ng-change="selectChanged()">
....


//controller
$scope.selectChanged = function() {
  if (/* Insert the condition you want to set cpp to false here */) ccp = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Solution